# jQuery UI Sortable Connected Lists Overflow only vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, horizontal-scrolling

See http://jsfiddle.net/rzsyhaj8/ for full code.

```
$( "#allfiles" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connected",
        forcePlaceholderSize: false,
        helper: function(e,li) {
            copyHelper= li.clone().insertAfter(li);
            return li.clone();
        },
        stop: function() {
            copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
        }
    });
        $(".connected").sortable({
            receive: function(e,ui) {
                copyHelper= null;
            }
    });
```

Dragging an item to the right results in horizontal scrolling. This is unwanted, since the user is supposed to drag&drop items from the left list to the right list.
I can't seem to get rid of this behavior except by disabling scrolling all together (overflow: hidden). 
Enabling scrolling overflow-y only results in this unwanted horizontal scrolling when dragging.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.appendTo()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo) body will do the scroll magic. However, in your case you will have to change some CSS to fix it.

```
$("#allfiles").sortable({
    appendTo: 'body'
    ......
});
```

Comment: No CSS changes required, this fixed it right away. Thank you so much! :-)